# How to make image inside a div bigger in HTML

Tags: html, css

Here's my issue, I'm gonna put my profile picture on my own portfolio website, but for some reason it's really small.

[image: Screenshot of the topnav bar]

If I make the image bigger via width and height the topnav becomes bigger along with it. I want it to be a circled image that's clickable. This is the HTML code that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styling.css">
    </head>
    <body class="bigbody" style="background-image: url('images/DSC_0761.JPG');">
        <div class="topnav">
            <a class="active" href="#home">
              <img class="profile" src="images/square-profile.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="#news">Newz</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
          </div>
          <div class="mainbody"> 
            <h2 class="titlediv">Wag1 Bruda</h2>
          </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.topnav {
    background-color: rgb(37,37,37, .3);
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
  
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;;
}
  
.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
    color: white;
}

body.bigbody {
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.mainbody {
    background-color: #00b7ff00;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 500px;
}

h2.titlediv {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;;
}

img.profile {
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi, a [mre] might help us to debug your problem

Comment: Sorry about that, lemme post my code

Comment: In order to make this reproducible you need to use images available online for the purpose of your illustrative, reproducible example, so we can see right away what the problem is. If you convert your code into a snippet, that would be even more helpful, because we could see your code in action via the click of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by the padding attribute you give to the "a" tags. Give the ".profile" class in the img tag to the "a" tag. and add the following css properties.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37, .3);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  color: white;
}

body.bigbody {
  position: relative;
  background-size: cover;
}

div.mainbody {
  background-color: #00b7ff00;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 500px;
}

h2.titlediv {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  
}

.profile {
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  padding: 4px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active profile" href="#home"><img src="https://gaveinjaz.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/opulent-profile-square-07.jpg" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#news">Newz</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Stack snippets are the equivalent of a jsFiddle, but they are built right into Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove (or reduce) the padding on the `<a>` element which contains your profile picture. One way to do that is to use the `:has` pseudo-class. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

```css
body {
  background: #7d9ec1;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(37,37,37, .3);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex; /* use flex instead of float */
  gap: 0.5em;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.topnav a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a:has(.profile) { /* targets an <a> element which contains a .profile element */
  padding: 2px;
}
  
img.profile {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%; /* makes the image a circle */
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="#home"><img class="profile" src="http://picsum.photos/100" alt=""></a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: While `:has` might work here - support is still not full. You could use the attribute selector instead `[href="#home"] { ... }` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) or since `home` will probably always be first, you could do `.topnav a:first-child { }`

Comment: True regarding `:has` support, but (a) it's only Firefox which is lagging, (b) Firefox will support it soon, and (c) I don't consider Firefox to be a major browser. As a developer I would rather be leading than lagging.

Comment: I'm typing this comment - using FireFox. Browser of development choice over here. HA! Yes, FF has a very low market share, but I would hardly say it's not a major browser.

Comment: And do you have this flag set? `layout.css.has-selector.enabled`

Comment: Nope. Set to `false`. I generally don't update any of the `:config` stuff unless I really need to test something cutting/bleeding edge.

Comment: I did some more digging, since every browser supports `:has()` besides FF, there is an active thread on [Mozilla Connect](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/when-is-has-css-selector-going-to-be-fully-implemented-in/idi-p/23794/page/4#comments) about `:has()`. It was supposed to be delivered in v116, but looks like other bugs prevented the release. Looks like it's a priority, but currently facing some blockers. I cannot wait for a native CSS parent selector.

Comment: Just set the flag and join the revolution

Comment: HA! I prefer to have browser settings to what real users will see. I am excited for native support!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width and height attributes from the img.profile in your CSS because they are currently set to a very small size (10px x 10px).
css
Define a size for your profile image using CSS. You can set the width and height in pixels or use other units like percentages.